# Función con referencia a múltiples estructuras en Arduino

Tags: arduino

Tengo múltiples estructuras, todas ellas con las mismas variables, pero que pueden variar el nº de elementos de los `*char[]` y las tengo situadas en el módulo *st1.h*

```
struct st1{ int n=2; char * s[2]= {"ab", "bc"};
  .
  .
struct stn{ int n=3; char * s[3]= {"a", "xx", "ddd"};
```

En el módulo principal *.ino* necesito llamar a una función mandándole cualquiera de estas estructuras

```
  st2 st;
  mp(st);
  st3 st;
  mp(st);
```

Y en el módulo *st1.cpp* tendré la función `mp(.....)`. ¿Cómo puedo declarar esta función para que me haga referencia a una u otra estructura? ¿Hay algún otro método para hacerlo?

Comment: y si en lugar de la estructura, le pasas a la funcion el contenido? si la funcion mp va a admitir todas esas estructuras (por tu logica de app), quizas te simplifique mas enviar unicamente el contenido de la estructura.